# Matplotlib: How to adjust space between x-axis and first horizontal bar

Tags: matplotlib, spacing

How to adjust space between x-axis and first horizontal bar. By default there is a large space between x-axis and the first horizontal bar plotted.

Here is my sample code:

```
    hbar_fig = plt.figure()
    ax3 = plt.subplot(111)
    ax3.barh(y_pos, data, self.hbar_width, align='center', color='#0073cf', edgecolor='#0073cf')
    matplotlib.pyplot.gcf().set_size_inches(10, len(data) * 1)
    ax3.set_xlim(0, max(data) + 1)
    plt.grid(b=True, color=self.x_grid_line_color, linestyle='-')
    plt.yticks(y_pos, map((lambda x, y: x + ' - ' + str(y)), app_data.keys(), app_data.values()), weight=self.x_font_weight, fontsize=9)
    plt.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', pad=12)
    plt.tight_layout()
    hchart_buffer.close()
    plt.close(hbar_fig)
```

Comment: Try adjusting the y limits

Comment: Actually I want to adjust spacing between the first horizontal bar just above the x-axis and the x-axis. The ylim() will adjust the spacing between the y-axis values.

Comment: can you edit the post adding the figure or a link to it to show better the problem?